# Creating functions in PostgreSQL 9.1 in Windows Enviroment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, postgresql, dll, dynamic-loading

I created a `dll` file in `visual studio 2010` and i am trying to use this `dll` in `PostgreSQL 9.1` to create a function but i am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  incompatible library "D:\visual_studio\DynamicLibrary\x64\Debug\funxx.dll":    
 missing magic block

HINT:  Extension libraries are required to use the PG_MODULE_MAGIC macro.
```

i am using `64bits windows.i` checked the documentation of `PostgreSQL` about `C` language functions and dynamic loading and it says

```
#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif
```

should be included for `dynamic loading` but it doesn't say anything about `C++` compatibility.
Anybody who knows how to deal with this issue?how can i remove that error to create functions using C++ in `PostgreSQL` in windows environment?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#EXTEND-CPP

Answer (score 3):

Did you compile as `C` or as `C++`?  If you used `C++` you will need to wrap your `PG_MODULE_MAGIC` in an `extern "C"` block, as per [writing extensions in C++](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#EXTEND-CPP).

If at all possible just write plain `c` and compile as plain `c`, keep C++ out of the picture. Mixing C++ code into PostgreSQL is complicated and hard, so it's not a good thing to do for a beginner.

If you absolutely must use C++ the sanest way is to write your code in C++, expose `extern "C"` interfaces to it where C++ objects are passed in and out as opaque `void` pointers or pointers to empty struct types. Then use the pure `c` interface you've exposed to write your Pg module. There are tools like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) that help produce such wrappers, but it isn't generally necessary for something like a Pg module.

You can use C++ directly in Pg modules with caution, but Pg's `longjmp` based error handling *will* totally trash your stack if you ever call `Pg -> C++ -> Pg` and get an error. Seriously, don't do it. Keep your C++ isolated.